# Understanding compiler options differences in visual studio 2010 and strict C++ compliance

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, compiler-errors

I am grading some homework C++ code and a student used a non-standard constructor for a vector of vectors:

```
vector<vector<double> > A(rows, cols);
```

where `rows` and `cols` are unsigned integers. The way we taught it in class is

```
vector<vector<double> > A(rows, vector<double>(cols));
```

following the fill constructor (2 in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)

I am using a batch file to compile all students codes with the command line

```
cl /O2 /EHsc /Tp <filename>
```

and this command threw this error at the student line mentioned above:

```
error C2664: 'std::vector<std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>::vector(std::initializer_list<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>,const std::allocator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>> &)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'unsigned int' to 'const std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>> &'
    with
    [
        _Ty=double
    ]
    Reason: cannot convert from 'unsigned int' to 'const std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
    with
    [
        _Ty=double
    ]
    Constructor for class 'std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>' is declared 'explicit'
    with
    [
        _Ty=double
    ]
```

But when I create a project and build it with the default parameters of MSVC 2010 it does not throw neither a warning nor an error there.

I am trying to learn what compiler option is responsible for allowing it go through without a warning in the IDE, and what I would switch it off.

I tried finding an answer in [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tb15w2z(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tb15w2z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but I couldn't an answer.

EDIT: I think this might be helpful to others: thanks to the comments I understand now the constructor called in the IDE is the range constructor (#3 in the link above).

Here's my particular question: both methods use the same compiler with different options (one the default from the IDE, the other one is stated above). The batch file throws an error, the IDE doesn't. I need help identifying what to change in the IDE's command line arguments so that it throws the error.

UPDATE: I included the error message.

UPDATE 2: It turns out the script was being run in a computer with MSVC 2013 and that was the difference

Comment: Quite honestly, I didn't really know how to title this. Maybe the right description would make it easier to find an answer.

Comment: Maybe rows and cols were converted to iterators, which is why there was no warning. Look at `range(3)` here in the constructor: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

Comment: @Kevin: I would title it something like *options for stricter C++ validation in VS* or something alike. I was surprised that it compiles, but I see how in the implementation... interesting :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: The constructor taking two iterators is selected, as from the point of view of the language `Iterator` holds no meaning and it can deduce the type to be `Iterator == unsigned int`. Now, the standard has specific wording as of what should be done there (which I cannot locate) that require this to have the same behavior as the constructor taking a size and a value, except that the implementation is doing an explicit conversion to `vector<double>` (instead of the implicit that would happen if that was the overload selected) and that is getting around the `explicit`...

Comment: I don't use VS, so I don't know about the specific flags, but that is a good lesson for those students: you cannot assume that because something compiles in one compiler / platform it is correct. I would recommend giving them an environment with g++/clang++ where they can cross-check their projects.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: What I remembered is the C++03 wording, in C++11 and above the standard requires that the construct is removed from overload resolution if the argument type does not qualify as an `InputIterator`. The implementation in C++11 has a bug and does the wrong thing (or the C++03 thing...)

Comment: To add to what @David said, it looks like this bug has been fixed in VS2013, where that constructor is SFINAE'd using `enable_if<_Is_iterator<Iter>::value>`. `_Is_iterator` is basically `!is_integral`.

Comment: @Kevin - looks like it's legal in pre-C++11, but the intent from the student would be more than likely, incorrect.  Don't know how you would detect "legal, but dubious" code without using the eyes, or getting a lint or lint-like tool that finds things like this.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I followed the IDE version and it calls the range version as @DavidRodríguez-dribeas said. I am still puzzled as to why the command line I use in my batch file throws the error and the IDE version doesn't. This is what I am trying to figure out so that they can make the change in their IDEs and avoid at least this type of "relaxed" compilation.

Comment: @Kevin: What is the error you get in the command line? Is the compiler the same (maybe the command line is picking vs2013?)? At any rate, don't look at this as a burden, but as an opportunity. Take some (a small amount, or even nothing, just make a remark) of points off and teach them a different tool chain. Take the time in class to explain that a compiler accepting the code does not mean that the code is correct. Give them a [different toolchain](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) and tell them to cross check their code in both... This is really an *opportunity* for teaching.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas thanks for your help. I included the error message now.

Comment: The computer I am using only have MSVS 2010 and 2008, but I am using the IDE for the 2010 version and using full path for the 2010 compiler in the batch file as well

Comment: @Kevin: Is that the full error message? It seems awkward as the left of the `:` mentions a different constructor (one taking `std::initializer_list<...>`. Maybe you did not copy enough of the error message to make full sense of the issue.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I am terribly sorry. I updated to contain the full error message.

Comment: Thanks you all for your help (someone suggested it earlier in a comment and I mistakenly thought it wasn't the case). There was a hidden installation of VS2013. I am sorry for my dumb mistake

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because your question was flawed: "both methods use the same compiler", except that your update 2 says that the root cause was running different compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're compiling at the command line you are not using VS 2010.

Here's what I get from a VS 2010 command line compile:

```
C:\so-test>cl /O2 /EHsc /Tp test.cpp
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:test.exe
test.obj
```

I get your error message when I compile from the VS 2013 command line (I get a similar but slightly different message from the VS 2012 command line).

I suggest that you look at the version number displayed to verify what version of the MSVC compiler you're using at the command line.

- VS 2010 is 16.00.xxxx (SP1 is 16.00.40219.01)
- VS 2012 is 17.00.xxxx (Update 4 is 17.00.61030)
- VS 2013 is 18.00.xxxx (Update 1 is 18.00.21005.1)

Comment: You are right! I was using a different computer that did have VS2013 when I ran the script. But didn't realize about it until now. Apparently the computer lab administrator decided to hide it until every computer has it. I am so sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 3):

Actually:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> a( rows, columns );
```

is legal, or at least it was legal until C++11.  It wasn't
intentionally legal, but the way the standard was worded, a
compiler was required to accept it.  (I think C++11 fixed this.
Although it did so a bit too late, since doing so breaks
previously legal code.)

The rule is (or was) simple, if overload resolution on the
constructor results in the constructor 
`<template Iter>std::vector::vector( Iter begin, Iter end )`
being chosen, and `Iter` deduces to an integral type, the code
must behave as if
`std::vector::vector( static_cast<size_type>( begin ), static_cast<value_type>( end ) )` 
were called.

Comment: Even though your comment correctly explains what constructor is being called, since my question was more about VS than C++ I am going to have to mark a different answer as correct. Your explanation was helpful though